# Cubism and metrics in Elasticsearch (statsd/diamond)

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, cubism.js

In a test environment setup, I'm using [diamond](https://github.com/python-diamond/Diamond) to send server stats and metrics to statsd and then using statsd's [elasticsearch backend](https://github.com/markkimsal/statsd-elasticsearch-backend) to send them to elasticsearch.

The elasticsearch data looks like this:

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [ {
      "_source":{"ns":"servers","grp":"server1","tgt":"vmstat","act":"pswpout","val":"0","@timestamp":"1438565055000"}
    }, {
      "_source":{"ns":"servers","grp":"server1","tgt":"vmstat","act":"pgpgin","val":"0","@timestamp":"1438565055000"}
    }, {
      "_source":{"ns":"servers","grp":"server1","tgt":"vmstat","act":"pswpin","val":"0","@timestamp":"1438565055000"}
    }, {
      "_source":{"ns":"servers","grp":"server1","tgt":"cpu","act":"total.nice","val":"0","@timestamp":"1438565055000"}
    }, {
      "_source":{"ns":"servers","grp":"server1","tgt":"cpu","act":"total.irq","val":"0","@timestamp":"1438565055000"}
    }, {
      "_source":{"ns":"servers","grp":"server1","tgt":"cpu","act":"total.guest","val":"0","@timestamp":"1438565055000"}
    }, {
      "_source":{"ns":"servers","grp":"server1","tgt":"diskspace","act":"_logs.byte_used","val":"209944576","@timestamp":"1438565055000"}
    }, {
      "_source":{"ns":"servers","grp":"server1","tgt":"diskspace","act":"_logs.byte_free","val":"887513440256","@timestamp":"1438565055000"}
    }, {
      "_source":{"ns":"servers","grp":"server1","tgt":"diskspace","act":"_logs.byte_avail","val":"842419666944","@timestamp":"1438565055000"}
    }, {
      "_source":{"ns":"servers","grp":"server1","tgt":"diskspace","act":"_logs.inodes_used","val":"11","@timestamp":"1438565055000"}
    } ]
  }
}
```

How would I go about having this data rendered using cubism? I can extract the data using elasticsearch.js, but just generally stumped about how I would go about getting this rendered, so that, I can visualize the time-series data for each of the different actions, for instance.

Comment: Does it have to be cubism or you need functional charts for these metrics?

Comment: @SergeiRodionov looking for functional charts using these metrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try https://github.com/bernd/statsd-influxdb-backend or http://graphite.wikidot.com backend.
For those backend http://grafana.org/ provides great visualisation tools.

If you choose Graphite cubism actually supports it too as a data provider according to their website: https://square.github.io/cubism/

Comment: To expand on this answer:  You don't want to use ES because it is not a time series database and you don't want to use Kibana because it can only chart 1 metric per query (charting min, max, and mean on one chart requires 3 queries instead of 1 query with a complex result set).  Use grafana and influxdb and don't fight a stack's defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ATSD [time chart](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/visualization/widgets/time-chart/). If this is functional enough, Axibase Time-Series Database Community Edition is free. By the way, it supports Graphite wire protocol directly so you can just stream data from your diamond daemons directly into the database.

Disclosure: I work for this company.